# How Facebook linting scraper work, and what are its expectations from my web site?

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags, meta

a short story,
I bought a new domain, and before I publishing it I used the free hosting of [kissr](https://www.kissr.com/)
then I couldn't be able to share the url at Facebook as it seems Facebook doesn't trust any thing at kissr,
[image]
By the way I let them know by completing the report.

Now I moved to Azure, but I still cannot post my URL for the same reason,
Using [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) it give my some different information.

> This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.
>
> Errors That Must Be Fixed
>   Error Linting URL: internal error occurred while linting the URL.

by clicking on See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL

> Document returned no data

What I have tried
1- moving from kissr
2- setting some facebook tags like

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="OamOam" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxx" />
<meta property="og:title" content="OamOam is the place where you can give your opinion and listen to others" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.oamoam.com/Content/images/Oam_Oam.png">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.oamoam.com">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="~/Content/images/OamOam.png" />
```

**Please point out what also can I do to solve this issue.**

Note the website is [OamOam](http://www.oamoam.com) using Angular, asp.net web API and hosted in azure

**Update 1:**
using the Facebook debugger tool for http://oamoam.azurewebsites.net/ which is the same as http://www.oamoam.com it shows some info about the site so i think it is not about the website content but the Facebook is just blocking the url because it was used with kissr before.

**Update 2:**
using service like https://sitecheck.sucuri.net I get a similar report

> Status:   Unable to properly scan your site. Content not found.

I don't even know what does it mean, as I can open the website normally from the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on that link and reach out to the facebook spam operations team. (please let us know)

> This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

they generally take a few weeks to look at the reports, but they unblock it if is not malicious. You need to appeal for them to look at it though.

There is no other work around to this.

Comment: I did, hopefully it will be unblocked.